# Get amount of days between 2 sql dates using jodatime: wrong date conversion (-1 day)

Tags: java, jodatime

I want to calculate the amount of days between 2 sql dates and I'm currently using:

```
Days.daysBetween(new DateMidnight(date1), new DateMidnight(date2));
```

However when passing the sql date `1900-01-01` it gets turned into: `1899-12-31`.

I get that this has to do with timezones, but how do I prevent this from occuring?

I also tried this using: Instants

Comment: You need to be a *lot* clearer about exactly what your data is. You should also avoid using `DateMidnight` if possible.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the code highlighting. I just added joda time (only using it here) since it seemed the cleanest way to calculate the amount of days.

Comment: That doesn't help - we still don't know **exactly** what's in `date1` and `date2`.

Comment: date1 = 1900-01-01 | date2 = 2013-03-15

Comment: Fetched from my database where they're stored as date objects.

Comment: I suspect the problem is basically that it's using the system default time zone. `java.sql.Date` is badly designed, unfortunately. It would help if you could write a short but complete program to demonstrate the problem, constructing the Date values directly.

Comment: indeed not reproducable when constructing them myself so it does indeed have to do with timezones.

Answer (score 1):

Using DateMidnight in combination with timezones is something you should avoid. Some days don't even have a midnight...

Try using `LocalDate.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay` instead of `DateMidnight`